# How to transform amino acid raw data to 3d tensor by one hot encoding by tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, multidimensional-array, one-hot-encoding, word-embedding

I have data that has amino acid raw input in a column. The maximum length of the value in the column of `df['wordstring']` is let's say 400. The total size of the vocabulary is 20 as you guess from the number of distinct amino acids. Furthermore, I have 1M rows of sequences let's say. I know how to create one-hot-encoding for each sequence. What I want to do is create a 3D matrix (tensor) that has 20 X 400 X 1M dimensions. Is there a way to do it by TensorFlow? Pytorch is also OK as an alternative.

[image: Data Frame]

For example: Assume that `s1 = df['wordstring'][0] (= 'a s g y t f t s y g i s w v r q ... ')` and assume that `len(s1) = 160`. Therefore, I have to obtain 160 one-hot encoded letters(words), on top of that I need to apply padding that makes the tensor  400 X 20. In a similar fashion, I have to create 1M of those. Then I am going to obtain my 20 X 400 X 1M dimensional tensor in order to apply LSTM, bidirectional LSTM, and so on.

A more mathematical way to say that having 20 components for the amino acid vector `A C D ....` as `<a1, a2, a3, ... , a19, a20>` and put it on the z axis. Secondly, since the max length of all sequences is 400, say that we have `<v1, v2, v3,... v399, v400>` vectors and put them on the y axis. Finally, since we have 1M distinct sequences we will have `<x1, x2, x3, ... , x1M>` long vector on the x-axis.

The difference between word embeddings is I need to encode each words (in my case each letters) 1 at a time. I do not need a vector representation for each document (in my case sequence) as usually work for common NLP problems.

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible input and expected output as an example? It's quite unclear how you want the encodings to be created and an example will make it super clear. Also, do comment here once you have updated your answer so that I get a notification and can look into it at the earliest :)

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is use an embedding layer as it is used in NLP models. This means:

1. Create a vocabulary that maps symbols into unique IDs.
2. Encode the input using the IDs.
3. Create an [embedding layer in TensofFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Embedding) that assigns a trainable vector to each. It will give you a tensor that you can use further in any NN.

You can do steps 1-2 on your own or use some TensorFlow utilities that you can find in [`tf.keras.preprocessing.text`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/text). You might find some hints in the [Word embeddings tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/word_embeddings).

It is also very well doable in PyTorch. In that case, you would use a [`nn.Embedding` layer](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Embedding.html). Respective utility functions are in a standalone package [torchtext](https://pytorch.org/text/stable/index.html).